# in android can i change the action bar window feature at runtime?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

ideally i'd like my main activity to have 2 views rather than starting a new activity; currently i'm using a view switcher to switch from map view and list view.

on my map view i want a transparent action bar.

on the list view i want a solid one (so the list items aren't inaccessible under the action bar).

is this something that is possible?

or am i forced to create 2 seperate activities and pass a list of custom objects through a bundle to make the transition between views as simple as possible.

the final goal is to have a iPhone style flipper animation when switching the views so it's like you're viewing the current stats/details on the back of the map view.
apparently such a transition animation might not be possible between activities, but i'm still looking into it.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `actionBar.show()` and `actionBar.hide()` to toggle ActionBar feature.

Comment: hey wayne, thanks for the reply, but i still need to show the action bar in both perspectives, not just show or hide it.